# When I type vim in terminal my bodhi linux complains emacs is not installed (bodhi linux)

Tags: vim, emacs, bodhi

```
jcress@jcress$  vim
The program 'emacs' can be found in the following packages:
 * emacs23
 * emacs23-nox
 * e3
 * emacs23-lucid
 * jove
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I can't figure out why.  I assumed something was wrong with .vimrc or ~/.vim so I moved these away from ~/ and still cant run vim.

I'm running bodhi linux

```
jcress@jcress$  uname -r
3.8.0-19-generic


jcress@jcress$  type vim
vim is aliased to `emacs'
```

Comment: What does `type vim` say?

Comment: I have basically a brand new install of bodhi.  I don't know why vim would alias to emacs by default... i'm really confused.  I'll google how to delete an alias.

Comment: Look in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`. If you don't find it, try `grep -r 'alias.*vim.*emacs' /etc ~` to look in other files. Could it be that you left your computer unattended and someone pranked you?

Comment: good prank, but this computer hasn't left my apartment in a while and nobody has had access to it.

Comment: Sounds like someone is playing the reverse http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html joke on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was ( for some reason ) vim was aliased to `emacs'.

This was being set by my .bashrc

I fixed it with unalias -a vim,
and I removed a line from .bashrc

I think this alias was added to .bashrc when I installed git.  I can't confirm this at the moment.